# Appending a java String one character at a time

Tags: java, string

I have a very simple question, in fact I'm a bit frustrated that I can't solve this on my own but here it is:

```
strBuffer += arg.charAt( i );
```

With this line I'm trying to parse a value and add it character by character to a new string. I'm doing this to seperate a single long string into an array of smaller string.

Example, this string

```
-time delayed -run auto -mode go_n_run
```

would become this array

```
strBuffer [0] = -time 
strBuffer [1] = delayed 
strBuffer [2] = -run 
strBuffer [3] = auto 
strBuffer [4] = -mode 
strBuffer [5] = go_n_run
```

So the line of code with the '+=' doesn't work, nothing gets put in my strBuffer. So I've tried something a little more "complex" that I found on a forum :

```
strBuffer.concat( new String( new char[]{arg.charAt( i )} ) );
```

But same result, nothing is put in strBuffer,

So, any hints would be appreciated

Thanks

EDIT : Here is the complete method

```
String[] args = new String[2 * ARG_LIMIT];
        int index = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < arg.length(); i++ )
        {
            String strBuffer = new String();

            if( arg.charAt( i ) != ' ' )
            {   

                            // The two methods I've tried
                strBuffer.concat( new String( new char[]{arg.charAt( i )} ) );

                strBuffer += arg.charAt( i );

            }
            else if( arg.charAt( i ) == ' ' )
            {
                args[index] = strBuffer;
                index++;
                strBuffer = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the class's API? If so, you'd see the method to use. So, why not use a for loop and the `append(...)` method? Edit: or better still, use split as @Perception posted. He should make that an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What actually gets stored in `strBuffer`?

Comment: What class is `strBuffer`? Also, looks to me like you could just use `String.split` instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Strings are immutable objects in java, you cannot add something to it. In addition a String is an object and Java does not have operators for methods. Guess indeed you wan't something like String's split method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that `strBuffer` is an instance of java's `StringBuffer`; if so - you should use `strBuffer.append()`.

But there's a way simpler method for doing the thing you want:

> String[] strBuff = arg.split(" "); //split by space

Answer (score 1):

You should use StringTokenizer. Here is the code:

```
// the first parameter is the string to be parsed, the second parameter is the delimiters
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("-time delayed -run auto -mode go_n_run", " ");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String s = st.nextToken();
    // append s to your strBuffer
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to rewrite [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

More specifically, you're doing this the hard way:

```
String[] args = arg.split(" ",2*ARG_LIMIT);
```

What you tried didn't work because strBuffer didn't survive to the next iteration of the for loop. This code would have worked:

```
    String[] args = new String[2 * ARG_LIMIT];

    int index = 0;
    String strBuffer = new String();

    for( int i = 0; i < arg.length(); i++ )
    {

        if( arg.charAt( i ) != ' ' )
        {   

            strBuffer += arg.charAt( i );

        }
        else if( arg.charAt( i ) == ' ' )
        {
            args[index] = strBuffer;
            index++;
            strBuffer = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try print out the character itself that you get from that line at the end.
If you get no character, then you obviously are not getting what you are looking for the in the argument array.

Comment: I'm can print the character just fine, but when I debug my array it just shows ""

Comment: I am trying to understand your code, but it seems kinda weird. Why are you doing this, if you find a space or no character?
strBuffer = "";